# Speaker and Bluetooth problems with ReplayKit Broadcast Extension

Tags: ios, replaykit

I have problems with the speaker using iOS ReplayKit Broadcast Extension to record the entire system UI.

Apple words: *Speaker* = loudspeaker, *Receiver* = hold phone to ear.

As per Apple standard, you declare your audio session behavior using `AVAudioSession`. In our case we are doing a video chat that should default to speaker when there is no headset (think support session recording the entire UI while chatting).

If we don't set the category with `defaultToSpeaker`, the default behavior is to use the receiver.

```swift
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
    .playAndRecord,
    mode: .videoChat,
    policy: .default,
    options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers]
```

But when I do this, Bluetooth headsets stop working. If I start using the speaker, then connect my AirPods, the Broadcast Extension keep using the speaker. (Wired headsets always work)

If I don't `setCategory`, there is some default session going but it defaults to receiver only.

This appears to be an Apple bug. It effectively means we must chose to either support Bluetooth headsets *or* to have the speaker when disconnecting the headset.

I've tried manually using `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)`, but this call seems to do nothing in the context of a Broadcast Extension.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Edit: File bug with apple: FB6485225 (openradar can't handle feedback assistant yet)